# JMeter with a software versioning tool

Tags: jmeter

Is it possible to use JMeter with a software versioning tool such as Git, so the test cases for a larger project can be done by a team ?

Also are there any other tools that can provide the same functionality that SVN gives but to JMeter test scripts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JMeter [JMX](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JmxTestPlan) tests are basically [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) files, as XML is basically a textual format it is version-control-system friendly so it should not be a problem to store them under SVN, Git, Mercurial, whatever.

Also if you work in a team you can additionally consider implementing high-level test architecture based on [Test Fragments](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) which can be used in the main Test Plan via [Module Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller). See [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921235809/https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) article for mode details on the approach.

Comment: Also, please do keep in mind that JMeter saves the test results to the JMX; you may want to click on "Run -> Clear All" before commiting your script, in order to avoid garbage.

Answer (score 2):

[VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/) is free. You can also create a previate repo in [GitHub](https://github.com/) (not FREE)

If more than 1 person is working on JMeter script, then I would suggest you to check this in creating a modular / reusable modules in JMeter.

**source**: http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-modularizing-test-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any version control tool. Git work very well with it.